# Can't login Unity Game Engine on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: games, unity3d

I found a build of Unity3d for Ubuntu 64 bit. I downloaded and installed it [using the instructions here](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/08/26/unity-comes-to-linux-experimental-build-now-available/)

After opening Unity, I can't login. It says

```
Service is not available, try again later
```

I tried to open it on Fluxbox, i3, ... with root. And nothing happens. Is the Unity server preventing login from Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Download http://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/linux/unity-editor-5.4.0b18+20160524_amd64.deb open deb in a deb installer, and Unity3D will work as intended.

Comment: This fixed it for me, but how did you find that link? All beta pages on *.unity3d.com refer to either windows or mac versions, or just the unity 5.1 version for linux, but no unity 5.4 for linux.

Comment: Where you got this link ? :O (Y)

Comment: Check last post at https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/

Answer (score 3):

```
LD_PRELOAD=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 /opt/Unity/Editor/Unity
```

Try this to launch from terminal.

[found on the Unity3d forum](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/service-not-available.350332/)

Comment: also mentioned as working here [Service not avaliable Unity3d error in Kubuntu](//askubuntu.com/q/786418)

Answer (score 0):

The newest Linux build can always be found at the bottom of this Unity Forum thread [forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/). It is probably the best idea to use that to profit from the newest developments and bug fixes. It should at least fix the "Service is not available" error. I post the link here, because I found the thread was not at all easy to find.