# How do I make Visual Studio Code default script editor in Unity3d?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, unity3d

I work in Ubuntu 16.04 and I have [Unity3d](https://unity3d.com/unity) installed. I want [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=linux64_deb) to be my default script editor within Unity3d.

Please [watch this 30 seconds video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M_IOdDS0GxMIzvY5r3Klp_y__5bjLlG2) and *don't confuse* **Unity3d** (the world-leading creation engine) with **Unity** (the default desktop environment of Ubuntu 16).

I put the shortcut of VSC, but I have to put an argument (e.g. : "$(File)"). I copy-pasted the location of the VSC, but when I try to open a script (e.g. `TriggerChecker.cs`), VSC opens but the script doesn't appear.

The only way to edit the script is to open VSC and add the project folder, the I have to search the script in the whole project folder.
Watch this [video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13slomNieOKCbwZ92IMd1C7o07dxwTpeH) to see how I need to search the script.
I want to make Unity3d to show directly the script, because when my project will become bigger, it would be easier for me to edit scripts without searching them.
As far as now, I only have one argument for VSC ("$(File)") that is ("$(/usr/share/code/code --unity-launch )"). This is the path to VSC's shortcut.

Could you help me solve this issue?

Comment: Are you still on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Visual Studio Code for Linux

- Download the latest version from the [official page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=linux64_deb).
- Install VSC and the dependencies via the command line:

  ```bsh
    sudo dpkg -i code*.deb
    sudo apt install -f
  ```
- The binary of VSC is `/usr/share/code/code`, but wen we execute `code` in the command line is executed the startup script **`/usr/bin/code`** and we will use it in the latest section.
- The binary may also be `/snap/bin/code` if you used the software installer to install VSCODE.
- You can use either `which code` or `whereis vscode` in order to find it.

### Unity3d for Linux

- Unity3d for Linux is Beta version at the moment and more details could be found in [Unity Blog](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/08/26/unity-comes-to-linux-experimental-build-now-available/). The latest version can be downloaded from ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/778966/566421) of the information): [this link](http://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/linux/unity-editor-5.4.0b18+20160524_amd64.deb).
- Install Unity3d and the dependencies via the command line:

  ```bsh
    sudo dpkg -i unity*.deb
    sudo apt install -f
  ```

### Set Visual Studio Code as default script editor in Unity3d

- Open Unity3d. In the **Edit** menu choose **Preferences**.
- In Unity Preferences choose **External Tools** (left side).
- Click on the button next to the ticket **External Tools Editor** and choose **Browse**.
- Navigate to the file **`/usr/bin/code`** and click on **Open**.
- **THE KEY STEP:** For **External Script Editor Args** fill **`$(File)`** - without quote marks!

<sup>I found that (bug) the quote marks, that are there by default,
are passed as characters, appended to the file name, thus VSC (the
external editor) opens a file that currently doesn't exist.</sup>

- **Close** Unity Preferences. That's it.

[image]

Comment: if you cant find the location of vscode, open terminal and write:
$ whereis vscode

Comment: May also be in `/snap/bin/code` if you used the software installer to install vscode

Comment: @Harry this could be a separate answer. Saved me some time, thanks! Or pa4080 could add this to their answer.

Comment: @ArthurZennig `$ whereis code` worked for me.